# Datanode never starts with all other daemon

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hiveql

Whene ever I start Ubuntu,all teh dameons run but not data node. I have to delete the data node to restart again.Please tell me a better solution.

```
starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-resourcemanager-sanjeebpanda-VirtualBox.out
localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-nodemanager-sanjeebpanda-VirtualBox.out
```

> ```
> hduser@sanjeebpanda-VirtualBox:~$ jps
> 4300 RunJar
> 5215 NodeManager
> 4926 SecondaryNameNode
> 5090 ResourceManager
> 4632 NameNode
> 5429 Jps
> ```

Can any one explain me the below highlighted part.
hadoop datanode

```
14/11/22 10:47:10 FATAL datanode.DataNode: Initialization failed for Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid unassigned) service to localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Exiting.
j**ava.io.IOException: Incompatible clusterIDs in /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode: namenode clusterID = CID-c834ad22-5221-4e60-a485-d84c67538ac8; datanode clusterID = CID-aa3ceda5-cc27-42e2-95ed-e88a097cbfb9**
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.doTransition(DataStorage.java:477)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.recoverTransitionRead(DataStorage.java:226)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.recoverTransitionRead(DataStorage.java:254)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initStorage(DataNode.java:975)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initBlockPool(DataNode.java:946)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPOfferService.verifyAndSetNamespaceInfo(BPOfferService.java:278)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.connectToNNAndHandshake(BPServiceActor.java:220)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.run(BPServiceActor.java:812)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
14/11/22 10:47:10 WARN datanode.DataNode: Ending block pool service for: Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid unassigned) service to localhost/127.0.0.1:54310
14/11/22 10:47:10 INFO datanode.DataNode: Removed Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid unassigned)
14/11/22 10:47:12 WARN datanode.DataNode: Exiting Datanode
14/11/22 10:47:12 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 0
14/11/22 10:47:12 INFO datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down DataNode at sanjeebpanda-VirtualBox/127.0.1.1
```

Temporary solution
I have to delete my datanode and restart all the process.

Comment: Try this thread, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26907878/hadoop-multinode-cluster-data-node-not-working-properly