# java.io.IOException: Incompatible clusterIDs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am installing Hadoop 2.7.2 (1 master NN -1 second NN-3 datanode) and cannot start the datanodes!!!
After trouble shouting the logs (see below), the fatal error is due to ClusterID mismatch... easy! just change the IDs.
**WRONG**... when I check my VERSION files on the NameNode and the DataNodes they are identical..

So the question is simple: INTO the log file --> Where the ClusterID of the NameNode is coming From????

LOG FILE:

---

```
WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: java.io.IOException: Incompatible clusterIDs in /home/hduser/mydata/hdfs/datanode: namenode clusterID = **CID-8e09ff25-80fb-4834-878b-f23b3deb62d0**; datanode clusterID = **CID-cd85e59a-ed4a-4516-b2ef-67e213cfa2a1**
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Initialization failed for Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid unassigned) service to master/172.XX.XX.XX:9000. Exiting.
java.io.IOException: All specified directories are failed to load.
atorg.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.recoverTransitionRead(DataStorage.java:478)
atorg.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initStorage(DataNode.java:1358)
atorg.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initBlockPool(DataNode.java:1323)
atorg.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPOfferService.verifyAndSetNamespaceInfo(BPOfferService.java:317)
atorg.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.connectToNNAndHandshake(BPServiceActor.java:223)
atorg.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.run(BPServiceActor.java:802)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Ending block pool service for: Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid unassigned) service to master/172.XX.XX.XX:9000
INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Removed Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid unassigned)
WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Exiting Datanode
```

COPY of THE VERSION FILE

---

**the master**

```
storageID=DS-f72f5710-a869-489d-9f52-40dadc659937
clusterID=CID-cd85e59a-ed4a-4516-b2ef-67e213cfa2a1
cTime=0
datanodeUuid=54bc8b80-b84f-4893-8b96-36568acc5d4b
storageType=DATA_NODE
layoutVersion=-56
```

**THE DataNode**

```
storageID=DS-f72f5710-a869-489d-9f52-40dadc659937
clusterID=CID-cd85e59a-ed4a-4516-b2ef-67e213cfa2a1
cTime=0
datanodeUuid=54bc8b80-b84f-4893-8b96-36568acc5d4b
storageType=DATA_NODE
layoutVersion=-56
```

Answer (score 13):

Just to summarize (and close) this issue, I would like to share how I fixed this issue.

On the **MASTER** and the **2nd Namenode** the Namenode VERSION file is under ~/.../**namenode**/current/VERSION.

BUT for **DATANODES** the path is different. it should look something like this ~/.../**datanode**/current/VERSION

ClusterIDs between the 2 VERSION files should be identical

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 8):

I also faced the same issue while installing 2.7.2. Data node is not coming up. Error shown in the datanode log file is

> java.io.IOException: Incompatible clusterIDs in
>   /home/prassanna/usr/local/hadoop/yarn_data/hdfs/datanode: namenode
>   clusterID = CID-XXX; datanode
>   clusterID = CID-YYY

What i have done is

```
HADOOP_DIR/bin/hadoop namenode -format -clusterID CID-YYY
```

(No quotes required for cluster id)

Comment: This FIXED the error for me. Seems like we need more info on why this happens.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add one more thing.

First, stop the dfs and delete the namenode and datanode directory/folders as specified in the hfs-site.xml.

And after that go to the ../namenode/current/VERSION file and copy the clusterId and replate the clusterID in ../datanode/current/VERSION file with the previously copied clusterID.